# Simple RSA Key Generation example

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers

I have two prime numbers:

```
p = 37
q = 41
```

And I need to find whether any of these prime numbers, 5, 7 or 11, can be used as a valid encryption key e?

My working so far:

Computer their product:

```
n = p * q =  1517
```

Compute Euler totient:

```
m = (p - 1)(q - 1) = 1440
```

Find greatest common divisor:

```
a = 41
b = 37
r = 41 mod 37 = 4
a = 37
b = 4
r = 37 mod 4 = 1
a = 41
b = 1
r = 41 mod 1 = 0
```

GCD = 1

What do I do now? **How would I find out which number could be a valid key?**

Does the encryption key has to be comprime with m (1440)?

As if I got it right, the answer should be 5.

***Sorry, but the this is not a duplicate, this is needed to help me understand the how to work out whether x, y or z is a valid encryption key, given two prime numbers!***

Comment: Also, I don't understand why or whether I needed to find the GCD, as if my answer is correct, it looks like I won't need that at all?

Comment: For RSA, $e$ must be coprime to $\varphi(n)$. In otherwords, $gcd(e,\varphi(n)) = 1$.

Comment: Cool, exactly what I thought. So in this case I think the answer is 7 or 11, as gcd(7, 1440) or gcd(11, 1140) = 1.

Comment: @mikeazo, would you mind writing a proper (two line?) answer?

Comment: The [other question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3432/555) is asked with $(e,N)$ given; when the present question is asked with $(p,q,e)$ given. So the present question is not quite a duplicate, and is computationally easier. Hint1: with $p$ and $q$ distinct odd primes, for $e$ to be valid you need $\gcd(e,p-1)=\gcd(e,q-1)=1$ ; or equivalently $\gcd(e,\varphi(p\cdot q))=1$ ; or yet equivalently $\gcd(e,\lambda(p\cdot q))=1$ (some require $e>2$, perhaps $e<p\cdot q$ or $e<\varphi(p\cdot q)$ ). Hint2: if $u$ is prime and $v>0$, then $\gcd(u,v)=1$ if and only if $u$ is not a divisor of $v$.