# With node-jose, Should I expect the JWK -> PEM conversion to be reversible?

Tags: rsa

I am using [node-jose](https://github.com/cisco/node-jose) to convert a particular JWK to a PEM, and then ... converting that PEM to a JWK.

The resulting JWK has the same e, but different n than the original. Should I be surprised?

I have read in [another answer here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3435/31193) that

> there are varients of RSA for which a public key might not meet these assumptions; they deal with the fact that $M^e$ might not have a unique inverse

Is that what I am seeing here?

If so, In my case, Will both combinations of {n,e} be able to verify signatures from the same private key? (I haven't tested this yet). If so, ... can someone point me to a more accessible explanation of why different RSA public keys (two different keys with same e, distinct n) can ... be equivalent in this way?

Or is this a conversion bug in node-jose?

Something else?

code:

```
const jose = require('node-jose');

let publicKeyJwk = {
        "kty":"RSA",
        "use":"sig",
        "n":"ANMPv9JuRDbixAFMT8UzJl6yfG4ZMj7pwtlQi02gPtnZGIUdKXzzOEbQjvbapI3Ot0WqLNzk6YfSPYBO0TAYlNBlTAQ2Hu-Di2Y6RniOzjvE5kIWjni81_3o_UAb6tYG4R7dUBj95uN_4NWzeuBoLQauDQl5tSHvNDb3cVg7Con4WIuH4KPs4XDAWkhNh4cnN0yINaBCn4fhJhy_-C4T3ewmJeD8akfg1TWya3RnhjrXll-KebFu_bf_ArJ7yeEreWL97BiuSbgW5hoilvMFhJ_vWw4OYt0j5YpjAXckh_sDGxVC8n1UryR3jJhADByg6vj1RnTPs5zZDwglSJB2RkU=",
        "e":"AQAB"
      };

jose.JWK.asKey(publicKeyJwk, 'json')
  .then (key => {
    let jwk = key.toJSON();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jwk, null, 2));
    console.log("\n");
    if (jwk.e == publicKeyJwk.e &&
        jwk.n == publicKeyJwk.n) {
      console.log('reflexive');
    }
    else {
      console.log('NOT reflexive');
    }

    let pem = key.toPEM();
    console.log(pem);

    return jose.JWK.asKey(pem, 'pem')
      .then (key => {
        let jwk = key.toJSON();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jwk, null, 2));
        console.log("\n");
        if (jwk.e == publicKeyJwk.e &&
            jwk.n == publicKeyJwk.n) {
          console.log('reflexive');
        }
        else {
          console.log('NOT reflexive');
        }

        let pem2 = key.toPEM();
        if (pem == pem2) {
          console.log('same pem');
        }
        else {
          console.log('NOT same pem');
        }

      });
  });
```

Comment: This is rather a Stackoverflow question about libraries, their correct usage and bugs.

Comment: I'll post it there. thanks.  But I believe there's an underlying theoretical question which I've posed, which could be answered here without addressing anything in the code.

Comment: That part of the answer not related to your problem. There is a problem during conversion, you need to get the same $e,d,p,q,n,d_p,d_q$ with conversions.

Comment: Cheeso, can you at least post the changed value of $n$? We're a crypto site, we should not have to run JS code to get to an answer.